# Is it possible for a dataframe in python which has a read_sql function to be unit tested?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-unittest

How do I unit test a dataframe in python which basically reads the value from a database?
To be a bit more precise here is the dataframe:

`df1 = pd.read_sql(db.session.query(Conversion_job).filter_by(name='update_bandit').statement, db.session.bind)`

Is it possible to write a unittest for the same? If yes then HOW?

Comment: What do you want to test? Whether the database is read correctly, or whether whatever operation that follows on the dataframe works? For the latter, mock up a pseudo database object that always returns the same response.

Comment: @timgeb I want to test if the database is read correctly